# This fragment inner class should be static

Tags: android

При генерации подписи в Android Studio выдается ошибка:

> Error:Error: This fragment inner class should be static
>   (com.example.goshany.myapplicationATimerPDA.MainActivityATimerPDA.ByebyeDialogFragment)
>   [ValidFragment]

на код:

```
public class ByebyeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builderout = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builderout.setMessage(R.string.exitTimer)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.Yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                      { finish();}
                    });
            builderout.setNegativeButton(R.string.No, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
            return builderout.create();
        }
    }
```

Если класс делаю static, то подчеркивается красным метод `finish()`.
Это происходит при *Build type-release*.
Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Использовать нестатические внутренние фрагменты крайне не рекомендую, но если очень хочется, можно заткнуть `lint`

```
android {
    ...

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

Стоит помнить, что вы можете не увидеть другие потенциальные ошибки, о которых среда могла бы вам сообщить.
При этом если использовать библиотеки поддержки 25 версии этот фрагмент будет падать.

Comment: Вариант getActivity().finish(); не проходит.

Comment: Извиняюсь за поспешный комментарий.getActivity().finish(); работает при классе static.